# PowerShell: cannot convert type SMO.server to type SMO.server

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2, powershell-3.0, smo

Error I'm getting from PowerShell:

```
Cannot convert argument "srv", with value: "[DBADEV\SQL2008r2]", for "SqlBackup" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server": "Cannot convert the "[DBADEV\SQL2008r2]" value of type 
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server"."
At line:23 char:1
+ $backup.SqlBackup($srv)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

I'm attempting to write a PowerShell script to restore a database from our Production box and into our DBADEV box. Below is the code I'm using which is then producing the error.

```
#Clear Screen
cls

#load assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Inquire"

# Restore [SQLSRV2k8-0102\SQL2008] instance

$BackupFile = Get-ChildItem "\\NetworkShare\r`$\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2008r2" | select -Last 1

$BackupFile

$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("DBADEV\SQL2008r2")
$res = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore
$backup = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup

$Backup.Devices.AddDevice($BackupFile, [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType]::File)
$Backup.Database = "AdventureWorks2008r2"
$Backup.Action = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupActionType]::Database
$backup.Initialize = $true
$backup.SqlBackup($srv)
$srv.Databases["AdventureWorks2008r2"].Drop()

$res.Devices.AddDevice($BackupFile, [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DeviceType]::File)
$res.Database = "AdventureWorks2008r2"
$res.NoRecovery = $true
$res.SqlRestore($srv)
```

The error seems a bit cryptic to me (as do most PowerShell errors). Any thoughts on why this is occurring? I'm also getting the error when I use Mike Fal's powershell script here: http://www.mikefal.net/2014/07/22/restoreautomation-powershell-module/

The one thing that seems to get me past this error is by passing "DBADEV\SQL2008r2" directly into SQLRestore, 
i.e. `$res.SqlRestore("DBADEV\SQL2008r2") instead of $res.SqlRestore($srv)`

This now generate an error stating "Restore failed for Server 'DBADEV\SQL2008r2'

Answer (score 0):

Well from my experiences this kind of errors appear because of wrong name/data type in variable.

I would try to escape \ in "DBADEV\SQL2008r2"

or try what I found on MSDN

```
$srv = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
Write-Host $srv.Information.Version
```

so it could look like

`New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(DBADEV\SQL2008r2)")`

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem.  I tried using an escape character ` so that my server is written as "DBADEV`\SQL2008r2". The one thing that seems to get me past this error is by passing  "DBADEV\SQL2008r2" directly into SQLRestore, i.e. $res.SqlRestore("DBADEV\SQL2008r2") instead of $res.SqlRestore($srv)